# How to Effectively use Laravel Repository pattern Binding

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern

I have one doubt in repository pattern in laravel,i will use repository pattern in my project but my project like e-commerce site (like flipkart,ebay,amazon..), currently i have 80+ tables. In future i will add many tables so how to effectively handle bind method in provider ? (my sample code look like below)

```
class RepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register(){
        $this->app::bind(
              'App\Repositories\User\UserRepositoryInterface',
              'App\Repositories\User\UserRepository');

        // Binding another repository if has multiple repository
//         $this->app->bind(
//             'App\Repositories\PostRepositoryInterface',
//             'App\Repositories\PostRepository'
//         );

        //Another approach of binding repository
//           $this->app->bind(
//             CustomerRepositoryInterface::class,
//             CustomerRepository::class
//         );

    }
}
```

Comment: this contextual binding doesn't effect your application either your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try injecting the concrete repositories instead of the abstract/interfaces, the container will resolve them.

Alternatively, you can use the "when/then" chain in your service provider:

```
$this->app->when(UserService::class)->needs(UserRepositoryInterface::class)->give(UserRepository::class);
```

You will have to repeat this for every service (or whatever class) that requires the RepositoryInterface in your service provider. What this does is to bind a concretion for a specific class when it requires an abstraction, that's why you'll need to do the same bind for every class that needs your interface.